# Connect to SQL Server remotely

Tags: sql-server, amazon-ec2, aws-dms

I am trying to use DMS as source for SQL Server database instance. Used the following image for creating the Windows server:

- Windows Server 2008 R2
- SQL Server 2012 Enterprise on Windows 2008 R2 R2 6.1.7601

From DMS when I connect to SQL Server, I get this error...

> Error Details: [errType=ERROR_RESPONSE, status=122506, errMessage=Failed to connect [122506] Network error has occurred, errDetails= RetCode: SQL_ERROR SqlState: 28000 NativeError: 18456 Message: [unixODBC][Simba]Login failed for user 'dba'. [122502] ODBC general error.]

How do I specify SQL Server as source?

Comment: `Login failed for user 'dba'`. It says that the connection does not have proper credentials provided or the user does not have access. Make sure that you have proper values included.

Comment: Who gave you a login of 'dba'? to use? That's not a default login name (but it certainly could have been added)